# Append an object to a list in R in amortized constant time, O(1)?

Tags: r, performance, list, append, big-o

If I have some R list `mylist`, you can append an item `obj` to it like so:

```
mylist[[length(mylist)+1]] <- obj
```

But surely there is some more compact way.  When I was new at R, I  tried writing `lappend()` like so:

```
lappend <- function(lst, obj) {
    lst[[length(lst)+1]] <- obj
    return(lst)
}
```

but of course that doesn't work due to R's call-by-name semantics (`lst` is effectively copied upon call, so changes to `lst` are not visible outside the scope of `lappend()`.  I know you can do environment hacking in an R function to reach outside the scope of your function and mutate the calling environment, but that seems like a large hammer to write a simple append function.

Can anyone suggest a more beautiful way of doing this? Bonus points if it works for both vectors and lists.

Comment: R has the immutable data characteristics that are often found in functional languages, hate to say this, but I think you just have to deal with it. It has its pros and its cons

Comment: When you say "call-by-name" you really mean "call-by-value", right?

Comment: No, it's definitely not call-by-value, otherwise this wouldn't be a problem. R actually uses call-by-need (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_need).

Comment: A good idea is to pre-allocate your vector/list: N = 100 mylist = vector('list', N) for (i in 1:N) { #mylist[[i]] = ... } Avoid 'growing' objects in R.

Comment: I accidentally found the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046336/here-we-go-again-append-an-element-to-a-list-in-r?lq=1 So hard to implement so easy algorithm!

Comment: @Fernando: ok but that's not generally applicable, it only works in scenarios where you can know the exact final length in advance (or maybe squeak by in you can use an upper bound to it).

Comment: the `lappend` approach has the advantage of populating an empty list (generally inside a loop). `l1 = list(l1, l2)`, starting with an empty list, puts an empty element as the first element.

Comment: Short answer: R has no built-in data structure that supports the objective stated in the title. See [JanKanis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32870310/8626917) for a custom implementation.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

If it's a list of string, just use the `c()` function :

```
R> LL <- list(a="tom", b="dick")
R> c(LL, c="harry")
$a
[1] "tom"

$b
[1] "dick"

$c
[1] "harry"

R> class(LL)
[1] "list"
R>
```

That works on vectors too, so do I get the bonus points?

*Edit (2015-Feb-01):* This post is coming up on its fifth birthday.  Some kind readers keep repeating any shortcomings with it, so by all means also see some of the comments below. One suggestion for `list` types:

```
newlist <- list(oldlist, list(someobj))
```

In general, R types can make it hard to have one and just one idiom for all types and uses.

Comment: This doesn't append... it concatenates.  `LL` would still have two elements after `C(LL, c="harry")` is called.

Comment: Just reassign to LL:  `LL <- c(LL, c="harry")`.

Comment: I guess this is the best you can do in R.  `c()` and `append()` (and the `lappend()` I've provided) all exhibit O(n^2) behavior. I was hoping for O(n lg n), which is what you would get with a dynamically growing sequence data structure in most languages, but it doesn't seem like R has that, at least built in.

Comment: This only works with strings. If a, b and c are integer vectors, the behavior is completely different.

Comment: Good find @AlexandreRademaker. The badness of `c(list(a=3, b=c(4, 5)), c=c(6, 7))` is staggering.

Comment: Try `identical(c(list(a=3, b=c(4, 5), c=c(6, 7))), list(a=3, b=c(4, 5), c=c(6, 7)))` and see that they are the same -- the `c(...)` around the `list()` is a null-op.  So what exactly is bad here?

Comment: @Dirk: You have the parens nested differently than I do. My call to `c()` has 2 arguments: the list I'm trying to append to, namely `list(a=3, b=c(4, 5))`, and the item I'm trying to append, namely `c=c(6, 7)`.  If you use my approach, you'll see that *2* list items are appended (`6` and `7`, with names `c1` and `c2`) instead of a single 2-element vector named `c` as is clearly intended!

Comment: I don't believe this works if you want to append an item whose value is `NULL`, although that is a rather unlikely scenario.

Comment: if the intention is to append $c=c(6,7),
we can do c(list(a=3, b=c(4,5)), list(c=c(6,7))

Comment: A rather simple experiment shows that the provided code snippets actually has linear time overhead (w.r.t vector size):
`v <- c(); for (i in 1:n) v <- c(v, i)`
As I continue to double n, the time *quadruples*.
Hence, this is not what the OP asked for (amortized constant-time append).

Comment: So is the conclusion `mylist <- list(mylist, list(obj))`? If yes it would be nice to modify the answer

Comment: For real bonus points, how do we do c(LL, x=y) so that a key is created for the value of x and its value is the value of y?  I'm sure eval is used somehow, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: I agree with Matthew that it would be nice to modify (I'd say "correct") the answer. The help for `c()` itself points out the problems when `obj` is a vector. My suggested correction/clarification along these lines was rejected as "makes no sense as an edit."

Comment: arrrg! nice answer. I just been struggling with combining lists of lists. I love R but the syntax can be frustrating.

Comment: `newlist <- list(oldlist, list(someobj))` seems  that the new sublist will recursively to join the oldlist. and `c(LL, c="harry")` only works for strings a number list. `lst[[length(lst)+1]] <- obj` works correctly for me.

Comment: `Ent = list(con = list(1:3)); con = 2:4; Ent$con = c(Ent$con, list(con)); con = 3:5; Ent$con = c(Ent$con, list(con))` this works for me either. list--sublist--vector

Comment: The method `newlist <- list(oldlist, list(someobj))` doesn't work. It doesn't append, it creates a new list with two elements where the first element is `oldlist`. The function _append()_ results in the desired behavior: `newlist <- append(oldlist, list(someobj))`

Answer (score 103):

The OP (in the April 2012 updated revision of the question) is interested in knowing if there's a way to add to a list in amortized constant time, such as can be done, for example, with a C++ `vector<>` container. The best answer(s?) here so far only show the relative execution times for various solutions given a fixed-size problem, but do not address any of the various solutions' [algorithmic efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency) directly. Comments below many of the answers discuss the algorithmic efficiency of some of the solutions, but ***in every case to date*** (as of April 2015) ***they come to the wrong conclusion.***

Algorithmic efficiency captures the growth characteristics, either in time (execution time) or space (amount of memory consumed) ***as a problem size grows***. Running a performance test for various solutions given a fixed-size problem does not address the various solutions' growth rate. The OP is interested in knowing if there is a way to append objects to an R list in "amortized constant time". What does that mean? To explain, first let me describe "constant time":

- **Constant** or **O(1)** growth:

  If the time required to perform a given task *remains the same* as the size of the problem *doubles*, then we say the algorithm exhibits *constant time* growth, or stated in "Big O" notation, exhibits O(1) time growth. When the OP says "amortized" constant time, he simply means "in the long run"... i.e., if performing a single operation occasionally takes much longer than normal (e.g. if a preallocated buffer is exhausted and occasionally requires resizing to a larger buffer size), as long as the long-term average performance is constant time, we'll still call it O(1).

  For comparison, I will also describe "linear time" and "quadratic time":
- **Linear** or **O(n)** growth:

  If the time required to perform a given task *doubles* as the size of the problem *doubles*, then we say the algorithm exhibits *linear time*, or *O(n)* growth.
- **Quadratic** or **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** growth:

  If the time required to perform a given task *increases by the square of the problem size*, them we say the algorithm exhibits *quadratic time*, or *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* growth.

There are many other efficiency classes of algorithms; I defer to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency) for further discussion.

I thank @CronAcronis for his answer, as I am new to R and it was nice to have a fully-constructed block of code for doing a performance analysis of the various solutions presented on this page. I am borrowing his code for my analysis, which I duplicate (wrapped in a function) below:

```
library(microbenchmark)
### Using environment as a container
lPtrAppend <- function(lstptr, lab, obj) {lstptr[[deparse(substitute(lab))]] <- obj}
### Store list inside new environment
envAppendList <- function(lstptr, obj) {lstptr$list[[length(lstptr$list)+1]] <- obj} 
runBenchmark <- function(n) {
    microbenchmark(times = 5,  
        env_with_list_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
            listptr$list <- NULL
            for(i in 1:n) {envAppendList(listptr, i)}
            listptr$list
        },
        c_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a = c(a, list(i))}
        },
        list_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- list(a, list(i))}
        },
        by_index = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a[length(a) + 1] <- i}
            a
        },
        append_ = { 
            a <- list(0)    
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- append(a, i)} 
            a
        },
        env_as_container_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
            for(i in 1:n) {lPtrAppend(listptr, i, i)} 
            listptr
        }   
    )
}
```

The results posted by @CronAcronis definitely seem to suggest that the `a <- list(a, list(i))` method is fastest, at least for a problem size of 10000, but the results for a single problem size do not address the growth of the solution. For that, we need to run a minimum of two profiling tests, with differing problem sizes:

```
> runBenchmark(2e+3)
Unit: microseconds
              expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
    env_with_list_  8712.146  9138.250 10185.533 10257.678 10761.33 12058.264     5
                c_ 13407.657 13413.739 13620.976 13605.696 13790.05 13887.738     5
             list_   854.110   913.407  1064.463   914.167  1301.50  1339.132     5
          by_index 11656.866 11705.140 12182.104 11997.446 12741.70 12809.363     5
           append_ 15986.712 16817.635 17409.391 17458.502 17480.55 19303.560     5
 env_as_container_ 19777.559 20401.702 20589.856 20606.961 20939.56 21223.502     5
> runBenchmark(2e+4)
Unit: milliseconds
              expr         min         lq        mean    median          uq         max neval
    env_with_list_  534.955014  550.57150  550.329366  553.5288  553.955246  558.636313     5
                c_ 1448.014870 1536.78905 1527.104276 1545.6449 1546.462877 1558.609706     5
             list_    8.746356    8.79615    9.162577    8.8315    9.601226    9.837655     5
          by_index  953.989076 1038.47864 1037.859367 1064.3942 1065.291678 1067.143200     5
           append_ 1634.151839 1682.94746 1681.948374 1689.7598 1696.198890 1706.683874     5
 env_as_container_  204.134468  205.35348  208.011525  206.4490  208.279580  215.841129     5
>
```

First of all, a word about the min/lq/mean/median/uq/max values: Since we are performing the exact same task for each of 5 runs, in an ideal world, we could expect that it would take exactly the same amount of time for each run. But the first run is normally biased toward longer times due to the fact that the code we are testing is not yet loaded into the CPU's cache. Following the first run, we would expect the times to be fairly consistent, but occasionally our code may be evicted from the cache due to timer tick interrupts or other hardware interrupts that are unrelated to the code we are testing. By testing the code snippets 5 times, we are allowing the code to be loaded into the cache during the first run and then giving each snippet 4 chances to run to completion without interference from outside events. For this reason, and because we are really running the exact same code under the exact same input conditions each time, we will consider only the 'min' times to be sufficient for the best comparison between the various code options.

Note that I chose to first run with a problem size of 2000 and then 20000, so my problem size increased by a factor of 10 from the first run to the second.

**Performance of the `list` solution: O(1) (constant time)**

Let's first look at the growth of the `list` solution, since we can tell right away that it's the fastest solution in both profiling runs: In the first run, it took 854 **micro**seconds (0.854 **milli**seconds) to perform 2000 "append" tasks. In the second run, it took 8.746 milliseconds to perform 20000 "append" tasks. A naïve observer would say, *"Ah, the `list` solution exhibits O(n) growth, since as the problem size grew by a factor of ten, so did the time required to execute the test."* The problem with that analysis is that what the OP wants is the growth rate of **a single object insertion**, not the growth rate of the overall problem. Knowing that, it's clear then that the `list` solution provides exactly what the OP wants: a method of appending objects to a list in O(1) time.

**Performance of the other solutions**

None of the other solutions come even close to the speed of the `list` solution, but it is informative to examine them anyway:

Most of the other solutions appear to be O(n) in performance. For example, the `by_index` solution, a very popular solution based on the frequency with which I find it in other SO posts, took 11.6 milliseconds to append 2000 objects, and 953 milliseconds to append ten times that many objects. The overall problem's time grew by a factor of 100, so a naïve observer might say *"Ah, the `by_index` solution exhibits O(n<sup>2</sup>) growth, since as the problem size grew by a factor of ten, the time required to execute the test grew by a factor of 100."* As before, this analysis is flawed, since the OP is interested in the growth of a single object insertion. If we divide the overall time growth by the problem's size growth, we find that the time growth of appending objects increased by a factor of only 10, not a factor of 100, which matches the growth of the problem size, so the `by_index` solution is O(n). There are no solutions listed which exhibit O(n<sup>2</sup>) growth for appending a single object.

Comment: To the reader: Please read JanKanis's answer, which provides a very practical extension to my findings above, and dives a bit into the overhead of various solutions given the internal workings of the C implementation of R.

Comment: Not sure the list option implements what it is required: >length(c(c(c(list(1)),list(2)),list(3)))
[1] 3
> length(list(list(list(list(1)),list(2)),list(3)))
[1] 2. Looks more like nested lists.

Comment: @Picarus - I think you're right. I'm not working with R anymore, but thankfully JanKanis posted an answer with a much more useful O(1) solution and notes the issue you identified. I'm sure JanKanis will appreciate your upvote.

Comment: @phonetagger, you should edit your answer. Not everybody will read all the answers.

Comment: "not a single answer has addressed the actual question" --> The problem is that the original question was not about algorithm complexity, take a look at the editions of the question. The OP asked first how to append an element in a list, than, several months later, he changed the question.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli - You are correct, thanks for pointing that out. I have revised the opening of my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 43):

In the other answers, only the `list` approach results in O(1) appends, but it results in a deeply nested list structure, and not a plain single list. I have used the below datastructures, they supports O(1) (amortized) appends, and allow the result to be converted back to a plain list.

```
expandingList <- function(capacity = 10) {
    buffer <- vector('list', capacity)
    length <- 0

    methods <- list()

    methods$double.size <- function() {
        buffer <<- c(buffer, vector('list', capacity))
        capacity <<- capacity * 2
    }

    methods$add <- function(val) {
        if(length == capacity) {
            methods$double.size()
        }

        length <<- length + 1
        buffer[[length]] <<- val
    }

    methods$as.list <- function() {
        b <- buffer[0:length]
        return(b)
    }

    methods
}
```

and

```
linkedList <- function() {
    head <- list(0)
    length <- 0

    methods <- list()

    methods$add <- function(val) {
        length <<- length + 1
        head <<- list(head, val)
    }

    methods$as.list <- function() {
        b <- vector('list', length)
        h <- head
        for(i in length:1) {
            b[[i]] <- head[[2]]
            head <- head[[1]]
        }
        return(b)
    }
    methods
}
```

Use them as follows:

```
> l <- expandingList()
> l$add("hello")
> l$add("world")
> l$add(101)
> l$as.list()
[[1]]
[1] "hello"

[[2]]
[1] "world"

[[3]]
[1] 101
```

These solutions could be expanded into full objects that support al list-related operations by themselves, but that will remain as an exercise for the reader.

Another variant for a named list:

```
namedExpandingList <- function(capacity = 10) {
    buffer <- vector('list', capacity)
    names <- character(capacity)
    length <- 0

    methods <- list()

    methods$double.size <- function() {
        buffer <<- c(buffer, vector('list', capacity))
        names <<- c(names, character(capacity))
        capacity <<- capacity * 2
    }

    methods$add <- function(name, val) {
        if(length == capacity) {
            methods$double.size()
        }

        length <<- length + 1
        buffer[[length]] <<- val
        names[length] <<- name
    }

    methods$as.list <- function() {
        b <- buffer[0:length]
        names(b) <- names[0:length]
        return(b)
    }

    methods
}
```

**Benchmarks**

Performance comparison using @phonetagger's code (which is based on @Cron Arconis' code). I have also added a `better_env_as_container` and changed the `env_as_container_` a bit. The original `env_as_container_` was broken and doesn't actually store all the numbers.

```
library(microbenchmark)
lPtrAppend <- function(lstptr, lab, obj) {lstptr[[deparse(lab)]] <- obj}
### Store list inside new environment
envAppendList <- function(lstptr, obj) {lstptr$list[[length(lstptr$list)+1]] <- obj} 
env2list <- function(env, len) {
    l <- vector('list', len)
    for (i in 1:len) {
        l[[i]] <- env[[as.character(i)]]
    }
    l
}
envl2list <- function(env, len) {
    l <- vector('list', len)
    for (i in 1:len) {
        l[[i]] <- env[[paste(as.character(i), 'L', sep='')]]
    }
    l
}
runBenchmark <- function(n) {
    microbenchmark(times = 5,  
        env_with_list_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
            listptr$list <- NULL
            for(i in 1:n) {envAppendList(listptr, i)}
            listptr$list
        },
        c_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a = c(a, list(i))}
        },
        list_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- list(a, list(i))}
        },
        by_index = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a[length(a) + 1] <- i}
            a
        },
        append_ = { 
            a <- list(0)    
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- append(a, i)} 
            a
        },
        env_as_container_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(hash=TRUE, parent=globalenv())
            for(i in 1:n) {lPtrAppend(listptr, i, i)} 
            envl2list(listptr, n)
        },
        better_env_as_container = {
            env <- new.env(hash=TRUE, parent=globalenv())
            for(i in 1:n) env[[as.character(i)]] <- i
            env2list(env, n)
        },
        linkedList = {
            a <- linkedList()
            for(i in 1:n) { a$add(i) }
            a$as.list()
        },
        inlineLinkedList = {
            a <- list()
            for(i in 1:n) { a <- list(a, i) }
            b <- vector('list', n)
            head <- a
            for(i in n:1) {
                b[[i]] <- head[[2]]
                head <- head[[1]]
            }                
        },
        expandingList = {
            a <- expandingList()
            for(i in 1:n) { a$add(i) }
            a$as.list()
        },
        inlineExpandingList = {
            l <- vector('list', 10)
            cap <- 10
            len <- 0
            for(i in 1:n) {
                if(len == cap) {
                    l <- c(l, vector('list', cap))
                    cap <- cap*2
                }
                len <- len + 1
                l[[len]] <- i
            }
            l[1:len]
        }
    )
}

# We need to repeatedly add an element to a list. With normal list concatenation
# or element setting this would lead to a large number of memory copies and a
# quadratic runtime. To prevent that, this function implements a bare bones
# expanding array, in which list appends are (amortized) constant time.
    expandingList <- function(capacity = 10) {
        buffer <- vector('list', capacity)
        length <- 0

        methods <- list()

        methods$double.size <- function() {
            buffer <<- c(buffer, vector('list', capacity))
            capacity <<- capacity * 2
        }

        methods$add <- function(val) {
            if(length == capacity) {
                methods$double.size()
            }

            length <<- length + 1
            buffer[[length]] <<- val
        }

        methods$as.list <- function() {
            b <- buffer[0:length]
            return(b)
        }

        methods
    }

    linkedList <- function() {
        head <- list(0)
        length <- 0

        methods <- list()

        methods$add <- function(val) {
            length <<- length + 1
            head <<- list(head, val)
        }

        methods$as.list <- function() {
            b <- vector('list', length)
            h <- head
            for(i in length:1) {
                b[[i]] <- head[[2]]
                head <- head[[1]]
            }
            return(b)
        }

        methods
    }

# We need to repeatedly add an element to a list. With normal list concatenation
# or element setting this would lead to a large number of memory copies and a
# quadratic runtime. To prevent that, this function implements a bare bones
# expanding array, in which list appends are (amortized) constant time.
    namedExpandingList <- function(capacity = 10) {
        buffer <- vector('list', capacity)
        names <- character(capacity)
        length <- 0

        methods <- list()

        methods$double.size <- function() {
            buffer <<- c(buffer, vector('list', capacity))
            names <<- c(names, character(capacity))
            capacity <<- capacity * 2
        }

        methods$add <- function(name, val) {
            if(length == capacity) {
                methods$double.size()
            }

            length <<- length + 1
            buffer[[length]] <<- val
            names[length] <<- name
        }

        methods$as.list <- function() {
            b <- buffer[0:length]
            names(b) <- names[0:length]
            return(b)
        }

        methods
    }
```

result:

```
> runBenchmark(1000)
Unit: microseconds
                    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
          env_with_list_  3128.291  3161.675  4466.726  3361.837  3362.885  9318.943     5
                      c_  3308.130  3465.830  6687.985  8578.913  8627.802  9459.252     5
                   list_   329.508   343.615   389.724   370.504   449.494   455.499     5
                by_index  3076.679  3256.588  5480.571  3395.919  8209.738  9463.931     5
                 append_  4292.321  4562.184  7911.882 10156.957 10202.773 10345.177     5
       env_as_container_ 24471.511 24795.849 25541.103 25486.362 26440.591 26511.200     5
 better_env_as_container  7671.338  7986.597  8118.163  8153.726  8335.659  8443.493     5
              linkedList  1700.754  1755.439  1829.442  1804.746  1898.752  1987.518     5
        inlineLinkedList  1109.764  1115.352  1163.751  1115.631  1206.843  1271.166     5
           expandingList  1422.440  1439.970  1486.288  1519.728  1524.268  1525.036     5
     inlineExpandingList   942.916   973.366  1002.461  1012.197  1017.784  1066.044     5
> runBenchmark(10000)
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
          env_with_list_ 357.760419 360.277117 433.810432 411.144799 479.090688 560.779139     5
                      c_ 685.477809 734.055635 761.689936 745.957553 778.330873 864.627811     5
                   list_   3.257356   3.454166   3.505653   3.524216   3.551454   3.741071     5
                by_index 445.977967 454.321797 515.453906 483.313516 560.374763 633.281485     5
                 append_ 610.777866 629.547539 681.145751 640.936898 760.570326 763.896124     5
       env_as_container_ 281.025606 290.028380 303.885130 308.594676 314.972570 324.804419     5
 better_env_as_container  83.944855  86.927458  90.098644  91.335853  92.459026  95.826030     5
              linkedList  19.612576  24.032285  24.229808  25.461429  25.819151  26.223597     5
        inlineLinkedList  11.126970  11.768524  12.216284  12.063529  12.392199  13.730200     5
           expandingList  14.735483  15.854536  15.764204  16.073485  16.075789  16.081726     5
     inlineExpandingList  10.618393  11.179351  13.275107  12.391780  14.747914  17.438096     5
> runBenchmark(20000)
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr         min          lq       mean      median          uq         max neval
          env_with_list_ 1723.899913 1915.003237 1921.23955 1938.734718 1951.649113 2076.910767     5
                      c_ 2759.769353 2768.992334 2810.40023 2820.129738 2832.350269 2870.759474     5
                   list_    6.112919    6.399964    6.63974    6.453252    6.910916    7.321647     5
                by_index 2163.585192 2194.892470 2292.61011 2209.889015 2436.620081 2458.063801     5
                 append_ 2832.504964 2872.559609 2983.17666 2992.634568 3004.625953 3213.558197     5
       env_as_container_  573.386166  588.448990  602.48829  597.645221  610.048314  642.912752     5
 better_env_as_container  154.180531  175.254307  180.26689  177.027204  188.642219  206.230191     5
              linkedList   38.401105   47.514506   46.61419   47.525192   48.677209   50.952958     5
        inlineLinkedList   25.172429   26.326681   32.33312   34.403442   34.469930   41.293126     5
           expandingList   30.776072   30.970438   34.45491   31.752790   38.062728   40.712542     5
     inlineExpandingList   21.309278   22.709159   24.64656   24.290694   25.764816   29.158849     5
```

I have added `linkedList` and `expandingList` and an inlined version of both. The `inlinedLinkedList` is basically a copy of `list_`, but it also converts the nested structure back into a plain list. Beyond that the difference between the inlined and non-inlined versions is due to the overhead of the function calls.

All variants of `expandingList` and `linkedList` show O(1) append performance, with the benchmark time scaling linearly with the number of items appended. `linkedList` is slower than `expandingList`, and the function call overhead is also visible. So if you really need all the speed you can get (and want to stick to R code), use an inlined version of `expandingList`.

I've also had a look at the C implementation of R, and both approaches should be O(1) append for any size up until you run out of memory.

I have also changed `env_as_container_`, the original version would store every item under index "i", overwriting the previously appended item. The `better_env_as_container` I have added is very similar to `env_as_container_` but without the `deparse` stuff. Both exhibit O(1) performance, but they have an overhead that is quite a bit larger than the linked/expanding lists.

**Memory overhead**

In the C R implementation there is an overhead of 4 words and 2 ints per allocated object. The `linkedList` approach allocates one list of length two per append, for a total of (4*8+4+4+2*8=) 56 bytes per appended item on 64-bit computers (excluding memory allocation overhead, so probably closer to 64 bytes). The `expandingList` approach uses one word per appended item, plus a copy when doubling the vector length, so a total memory usage of up to 16 bytes per item. Since the memory is all in one or two objects the per-object overhead is insignificant. I haven't looked deeply into the `env` memory usage, but I think it will be closer to `linkedList`.

Comment: what is the point of keeping the list option if it does not solve the problem we are trying to solve?

Comment: @Picarus I'm not sure what you mean. Why I kept it in the benchmark? As comparison with the other options. The `list_` option is faster and could be useful if you don't need to convert to a normal list, i.e. if you use the result as a stack.

Comment: @Gabor Csardi posted a faster way to convert environments back to lists in a different question at stackoverflow.com/a/29482211/264177. I benchmarked that as well on my system. It is about twice as fast better_env_as_container but still slower than linkedList and expandingList.

Comment: Deeply nested (n=99999) lists seem manageable and tolerable for certain applications: Anyone want to benchmark [nestoR](https://github.com/dmparrishphd/tRivia/blob/master/nestoR)? (I'm still a bit of a noob at the `environment` stuff I used for nestoR.) My bottleneck is almost always human time spent coding and doing data analysis, but I appreciate the benchmarks I've found on this post. As for memory overhead, I would not mind up to about a kB per node for my applications. I hold on to large arrays, etc.

Answer (score 16):

In the Lisp we did it this way:

```
> l <- c(1)
> l <- c(2, l)
> l <- c(3, l)
> l <- rev(l)
> l
[1] 1 2 3
```

though it was 'cons', not just 'c'. If you need to start with an empy list, use l <- NULL.

Comment: Excellent! All the other solutions return some weird list of lists.

Comment: In Lisp, prepending to a list is an O(1) operation, while appending runs in O(n), @flies. The need for reversion is outweighed by performance gain. This is not the case in R. Not even in pairlist, which generally resembles List lists the most.

Comment: @Palec "This is not the case in R"  - I'm not sure which "this" you're referring to.  Are you saying that appending is not O(1), or it's not O(n)?

Comment: I’m saying that if you were coding in Lisp, your approach would be inefficient, @flies. That remark was meant to explain why the answer is written as it is. In R, the two approaches are on par performance-wise, AFAIK. But now I’m not sure about the amortized complexity. Haven’t touched R since about the time my previous comment was written.

Comment: In R, this approach will be O(n). The `c()` function copies its arguments into a new vector/list and returns that.

Answer (score 7):

You want something like this maybe?

```
> push <- function(l, x) {
   lst <- get(l, parent.frame())
   lst[length(lst)+1] <- x
   assign(l, lst, envir=parent.frame())
 }
> a <- list(1,2)
> push('a', 6)
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

It's not a very polite function (assigning to `parent.frame()` is kind of rude) but IIUYC it's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you pass in the list variable as a quoted string, you can reach it from within the function like:

```
push <- function(l, x) {
  assign(l, append(eval(as.name(l)), x), envir=parent.frame())
}
```

so:

```
> a <- list(1,2)
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

> push("a", 3)
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

>
```

or for extra credit:

```
> v <- vector()
> push("v", 1)
> v
[1] 1
> push("v", 2)
> v
[1] 1 2
>
```

Comment: This is basically the behavior that I want, however it still calls append internally, resulting in O(n^2) performance.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you don't think your first method won't work.  You have a bug in the lappend function: length(list) should be length(lst).  This works fine and returns a list with the appended obj.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  There was a bug in the code and I've fixed it.  I've tested the `lappend()` that I've provided and it seems to perform about as well as c() and append(), all of which exhibit O(n^2) behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I have made a small comparison of methods mentioned here.

```
n = 1e+4
library(microbenchmark)
### Using environment as a container
lPtrAppend <- function(lstptr, lab, obj) {lstptr[[deparse(substitute(lab))]] <- obj}
### Store list inside new environment
envAppendList <- function(lstptr, obj) {lstptr$list[[length(lstptr$list)+1]] <- obj} 

microbenchmark(times = 5,  
        env_with_list_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
            listptr$list <- NULL
            for(i in 1:n) {envAppendList(listptr, i)}
            listptr$list
        },
        c_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a = c(a, list(i))}
        },
        list_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- list(a, list(i))}
        },
        by_index = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a[length(a) + 1] <- i}
            a
        },
        append_ = { 
            a <- list(0)    
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- append(a, i)} 
            a
        },
        env_as_container_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
            for(i in 1:n) {lPtrAppend(listptr, i, i)} 
            listptr
        }   
)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
    env_with_list_  188.9023  198.7560  224.57632  223.2520  229.3854  282.5859     5  a 
                c_ 1275.3424 1869.1064 2022.20984 2191.7745 2283.1199 2491.7060     5   b
             list_   17.4916   18.1142   22.56752   19.8546   20.8191   36.5581     5  a 
          by_index  445.2970  479.9670  540.20398  576.9037  591.2366  607.6156     5  a 
           append_ 1140.8975 1316.3031 1794.10472 1620.1212 1855.3602 3037.8416     5   b
 env_as_container_  355.9655  360.1738  399.69186  376.8588  391.7945  513.6667     5  a
```

Comment: This is great info: would *never ever* have guessed that the `list = list` were not only the winner - but by 1 to 2 orders or magnitude!

Comment: This comparison is not valid: `list_` does not create a list of integers as expected. It will contain list of lists. At each iteration, a new list is created with 2 elements, one is the new integer and the other one is the previous version of the same list. Because values are not overwritten, a simple copy by reference is done internally. It's why it's so fast, but we don't have the same object at all. For all the other examples, we have a list of length n+1

Comment: @DavidBellot it is correct, it is meant there for benchmark level. You can flatten it at then end :)

Answer (score 3):

try this function lappend

```
lappend <- function (lst, ...){
  lst <- c(lst, list(...))
  return(lst)
}
```

and other suggestions from this page [Add named vector to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031819/add-named-vector-to-a-list/12978667#12978667)

Bye.

Answer (score 3):

in fact there is a subtelty with the `c()` function. If you do:

```
x <- list()
x <- c(x,2)
x = c(x,"foo")
```

you will obtain as expected:

```
[[1]]
[1]

[[2]]
[1] "foo"
```

but if you add a matrix with `x <- c(x, matrix(5,2,2)`, your list will have another 4 elements of value `5` !
You would better do:

```
x <- c(x, list(matrix(5,2,2))
```

It works for any other object and you will obtain as expected:

```
[[1]]
[1]

[[2]]
[1] "foo"

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]    5    5
```

Finally, your function becomes:

```
push <- function(l, ...) c(l, list(...))
```

and it works for any type of object. You can be smarter and do:

```
push_back <- function(l, ...) c(l, list(...))
push_front <- function(l, ...) c(list(...), l)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward way to add items to an R List:

```
# create an empty list:
small_list = list()

# now put some objects in it:
small_list$k1 = "v1"
small_list$k2 = "v2"
small_list$k3 = 1:10

# retrieve them the same way:
small_list$k1
# returns "v1"

# "index" notation works as well:
small_list["k2"]
```

Or programmatically:

```
kx = paste(LETTERS[1:5], 1:5, sep="")
vx = runif(5)
lx = list()
cn = 1

for (itm in kx) { lx[itm] = vx[cn]; cn = cn + 1 }

print(length(lx))
# returns 5
```

Comment: This isn't really appending. What if I have 100 objects and I want to append them to a list programmatically? R has an `append()` function, but it's really a concatenate function and it only works on vectors.

Comment: `append()` works on vectors and lists, and it is a true append (which is basically the same as concatenate, so I don't see what your problem is)

Comment: An append function should mutate an existing object, not create a new one.  A true append would not have O(N^2) behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is **actually** pass by reference (pointer) to the function-- create a new environment (which are passed by reference to functions) with the list added to it:

```
listptr=new.env(parent=globalenv())
listptr$list=mylist

#Then the function is modified as:
lPtrAppend <- function(lstptr, obj) {
    lstptr$list[[length(lstptr$list)+1]] <- obj
}
```

Now you are only modifying the existing list (not creating a new one)

Comment: This appears to have quadratic time complexity again. The problem is obviously that list/vector resize is not implemented in the way it is usually implemented in most languages.

Comment: Yes-- looks like the appending at the end is very slow-- probably b/c lists are recursive, and R is best at vector operations rather than loop type operations. Its much better to do:

Comment: system.time(for(i in c(1:10000) mylist[i]=i) (a few seconds), or better yet do it all in one operation: system.time(mylist=list(1:100000)) (less than a second), then modifying that preallocated list with the for loop will also be faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `list.append` from the `rlist` ([link to the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlist/versions/0.4.6.1/topics/list.append))

```
require(rlist)
LL <- list(a="Tom", b="Dick")
list.append(LL,d="Pam",f=c("Joe","Ann"))
```

It's very simple and efficient.

Comment: doesnt look like R to me... Python?

Comment: I made an edit and tried it out: It is freaking slow. Better use the `c()` or `list`-method. Both are way faster.

Comment: Looking a the code for `rlist::list.append()`, it's essentially a wrapper around `base::c()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> LL<-list(1:4)

> LL

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

> LL<-list(c(unlist(LL),5:9))

> LL

[[1]]
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: I don't think this is the kind of appending the OP was looking for.

Comment: This is not appending elements in a list. Here you are increasing the elements of the integer vector, which is the only element of the list. The list has only one element, an integer vector.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question and I hope my thought below could contribute an way of solution to it. This method do give a flat list without indexing, but it does have list and unlist to avoid the nesting structures. I'm not sure about the speed since I don't know how to benchmark it.

```
a_list<-list()
for(i in 1:3){
  a_list<-list(unlist(list(unlist(a_list,recursive = FALSE),list(rnorm(2))),recursive = FALSE))
}
a_list

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] -0.8098202  1.1035517

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.6804520 0.4664394

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 0.15592354 0.07424637
```

Comment: What I want to add is that it does give a two level nested list, but that's it. The way how list and unlist working is not very clear to me, but this is the result by testing the code

Answer (score 0):

For validation I ran the benchmark code provided by @Cron. There is one major difference (in addition to running faster on the newer i7 processor): the `by_index` now performs nearly as well as the `list_`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
    env_with_list_ 167.882406 175.969269 185.966143 181.817187 185.933887
                c_ 485.524870 501.049836 516.781689 518.637468 537.355953
             list_   6.155772   6.258487   6.544207   6.269045   6.290925
          by_index   9.290577   9.630283   9.881103   9.672359  10.219533
           append_ 505.046634 543.319857 542.112303 551.001787 553.030110
 env_as_container_ 153.297375 154.880337 156.198009 156.068736 156.800135
```

For reference here is the benchmark code copied verbatim from @Cron's answer (just in case he later changes the contents):

```
n = 1e+4
library(microbenchmark)
### Using environment as a container
lPtrAppend <- function(lstptr, lab, obj) {lstptr[[deparse(substitute(lab))]] <- obj}
### Store list inside new environment
envAppendList <- function(lstptr, obj) {lstptr$list[[length(lstptr$list)+1]] <- obj}

microbenchmark(times = 5,
        env_with_list_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
            listptr$list <- NULL
            for(i in 1:n) {envAppendList(listptr, i)}
            listptr$list
        },
        c_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a = c(a, list(i))}
        },
        list_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- list(a, list(i))}
        },
        by_index = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a[length(a) + 1] <- i}
            a
        },
        append_ = {
            a <- list(0)
            for(i in 1:n) {a <- append(a, i)}
            a
        },
        env_as_container_ = {
            listptr <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
            for(i in 1:n) {lPtrAppend(listptr, i, i)}
            listptr
        }
)
```

Comment: See my comment above. The `list_` does not provide the same result as the others. So this comparison is not valid!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following benchmark:

```
bench=function(...,n=1,r=3){
  a=match.call(expand.dots=F)$...
  t=matrix(ncol=length(a),nrow=n)
  for(i in 1:length(a))for(j in 1:n){t1=Sys.time();eval(a[[i]],parent.frame());t[j,i]=Sys.time()-t1}
  o=t(apply(t,2,function(x)c(median(x),min(x),max(x),mean(x))))
  round(1e3*`dimnames<-`(o,list(names(a),c("median","min","max","mean"))),r)
}

ns=10^c(3:7)
m=sapply(ns,function(n)bench(n=5,
  `vector at length + 1`={l=c();for(i in 1:n)l[length(l)+1]=i},
  `vector at index`={l=c();for(i in 1:n)l[i]=i},
  `vector at index, initialize with type`={l=integer();for(i in 1:n)l[i]=i},
  `vector at index, initialize with length`={l=vector(length=n);for(i in 1:n)l[i]=i},
  `vector at index, initialize with type and length`={l=integer(n);for(i in 1:n)l[i]=i},
  `list at length + 1`={l=list();for(i in 1:n)l[[length(l)+1]]=i},
  `list at index`={l=list();for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i},
  `list at index, initialize with length`={l=vector('list',n);for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i},
  `list at index, initialize with double length, remove null`={l=vector("list",2*n);for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i;l=head(l,i)},
  `list at index, double when full, get length from variable`={len=1;l=list();for(i in 1:n){l[[i]]=i;if(i==len){len=len*2;length(l)=len}};l=head(l,i)},
  `list at index, double when full, check length inside loop`={len=1;l=list();for(i in 1:n){l[[i]]=i;if(i==length(l)){length(l)=i*2}};l=head(l,i)},
  `nested lists`={l=list();for(i in 1:n)l=list(l,i)},
  `nested lists with unlist`={if(n<=1e5){l=list();for(i in 1:n)l=list(l,i);o=unlist(l)}},
  `nested lists with manual unlist`={l=list();for(i in 1:n)l=list(l,i);o=integer(n);for(i in 1:n){o[n-i+1]=l[[2]];l=l[[1]]}},
  `JanKanis better_env_as_container`={env=new.env(hash=T,parent=globalenv());for(i in 1:n)env[[as.character(i)]]=i},
  `JanKanis inlineLinkedList`={a=list();for(i in 1:n)a=list(a,i);b=vector('list',n);head=a;for(i in n:1){b[[i]]=head[[2]];head=head[[1]]}},
  `JanKanis inlineExpandingList`={l=vector('list',10);cap=10;len=0;for(i in 1:n){if(len==cap){l=c(l,vector('list',cap));cap=cap*2};len=len+1;l[[len]]=i};l[1:len]},
  `c`={if(n<=1e5){l=c();for(i in 1:n)l=c(l,i)}},
  `append vector`={if(n<=1e5){l=integer(n);for(i in 1:n)l=append(l,i)}},
  `append list`={if(n<=1e9){l=list();for(i in 1:n)l=append(l,i)}}
)[,1])

m[rownames(m)%in%c("nested lists with unlist","c","append vector","append list"),4:5]=NA
m2=apply(m,2,function(x)formatC(x,max(0,2-ceiling(log10(min(x,na.rm=T)))),format="f"))
m3=apply(rbind(paste0("1e",log10(ns)),m2),2,function(x)formatC(x,max(nchar(x)),format="s"))
writeLines(apply(cbind(m3,c("",rownames(m))),1,paste,collapse=" "))
```

Output:

```
 1e3   1e4   1e5  1e6   1e7
2.35  24.5   245 2292 27146 vector at length + 1
0.61   5.9    60  590  7360 vector at index
0.61   5.9    64  587  7132 vector at index, initialize with type
0.56   5.6    54  523  6418 vector at index, initialize with length
0.54   5.5    55  522  6371 vector at index, initialize with type and length
2.65  28.8   299 3955 48204 list at length + 1
0.93   9.2    96 1605 13480 list at index
0.58   5.6    57  707  8461 list at index, initialize with length
0.62   5.8    59  739  9413 list at index, initialize with double length, remove null
0.88   8.4    81  962 11872 list at index, double when full, get length from variable
0.96   9.5    92 1264 15813 list at index, double when full, check length inside loop
0.21   1.9    22  426  3826 nested lists
0.25   2.4    29   NA    NA nested lists with unlist
2.85  27.5   295 3065 31427 nested lists with manual unlist
1.65  20.2   293 6505  8835 JanKanis better_env_as_container
1.11  10.1   110 1534 27119 JanKanis inlineLinkedList
2.66  26.3   266 3592 47120 JanKanis inlineExpandingList
1.22 118.6 15466   NA    NA c
3.64 512.0 45167   NA    NA append vector
6.35 664.8 71399   NA    NA append list
```

The table above shows the median time for each method and not the mean time, because occasionally a single run took much longer than a typical run which distorted the mean running time. But none of the methods became much faster on subsequent runs after the first run, so the minimum time and median time were typically similar for each method.

The method "vector at index" (`l=c();for(i in 1:n)l[i]=i`) was about 5 times faster than "vector at length + 1" (`l=c();for(i in 1:n)l[length(l)]=i`), because getting the length of the vector took longer than adding an element to the vector. When I initialized the vector with a predetermined length, it made the code about 20% faster, but initializing with a specific type didn't make a difference, because the type just needs to be changed once when the first item is added to the vector. And in the case of lists, when you compare the methods "list at index" and "list at index initialized with length", initializing the list with a predetermined length made a bigger difference as the length of the list increased, because it made the code about twice as fast at length 1e6 but about 3 times as fast at length 1e7.

The method "list at index" (`l=list();for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i`) was about 3-4 times faster than the method "list at length + 1" (`l=list();for(i in 1:n)l[[length(l)+1]]=i`).

The linked list and expanding list methods by JanKanis were slower than "list at index" but faster than "list at length + 1". The linked list was faster than the expanding list.

Some people claim that the `append` function is faster than the `c` function, but in my benchmark `append` was about 3-4 times slower than `c`.

In the table above, the lengths 1e6 and 1e7 and are missing for three methods: for "c", "append vector", and "append list" because they had quadratic time complexity, and for "nested lists with unlist" because it resulted in a stack overflow.

The "nested lists" option was the fastest, but it doesn't include the time that it takes to flatten the list. When I used the `unlist` function to flatten the nested list, I got a stack overflow when the length of the list was around 1.26e5 or higher, because the `unlist` function calls itself recursively by default: `n=1.26e5;l=list();for(i in 1:n)l=list(l,list(i));u=unlist(l)`. And when I used repeated calls of `unlist(recursive=F)`, it took about 4 seconds to run even for a list with only 10,000 items: `for(i in 1:n)l=unlist(l,recursive=F)`. But when I did the unlisting manually, it only took about 0.3 seconds to run for a list with a million items: `o=integer(n);for(i in 1:n){o[n-i+1]=l[[2]];l=l[[1]]}`.

If you don't know how many items you are going to append to a list in advance but you know the maximum number of items, then you can try to initialize the list at the maximum length and then later remove NULL values. Or another approach is to double the size of the list every time the list becomes full (which you can do faster if you have one variable for the length of the list and another variable for the number of items you have added to the list, so then you don't have to check the length of the list object on each iteration of a loop):

```
ns=10^c(2:7)
m=sapply(ns,function(n)bench(n=5,
  `list at index`={l=list();for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i},
  `list at length + 1`={l=list();for(i in 1:n)l[[length(l)+1]]=i},
  `list at index, initialize with length`={l=vector("list",n);for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i},
  `list at index, initialize with double length, remove null`={l=vector("list",2*n);for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i;l=head(l,i)},
  `list at index, initialize with length 1e7, remove null`={l=vector("list",1e7);for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i;l=head(l,i)},
  `list at index, initialize with length 1e8, remove null`={l=vector("list",1e8);for(i in 1:n)l[[i]]=i;l=head(l,i)},
  `list at index, double when full, get length from variable`={len=1;l=list();for(i in 1:n){l[[i]]=i;if(i==len){len=len*2;length(l)=len}};l=head(l,i)},
  `list at index, double when full, check length inside loop`={len=1;l=list();for(i in 1:n){l[[i]]=i;if(i==length(l)){length(l)=i*2}};l=head(l,i)}
)[,1])

m2=apply(m,2,function(x)formatC(x,max(0,2-ceiling(log10(min(x)))),format="f"))
m3=apply(rbind(paste0("1e",log10(ns)),m2),2,function(x)formatC(x,max(nchar(x)),format="s"))
writeLines(apply(cbind(m3,c("",rownames(m))),1,paste,collapse=" "))
```

Output:

```
  1e4 1e5  1e6   1e7
  9.3 102 1225 13250 list at index
 27.4 315 3820 45920 list at length + 1
  5.7  58  726  7548 list at index, initialize with length
  5.8  60  748  8057 list at index, initialize with double length, remove null
 33.4  88  902  7684 list at index, initialize with length 1e7, remove null
333.2 393 2691 12245 list at index, initialize with length 1e8, remove null
  8.6  83 1032 10611 list at index, double when full, get length from variable
  9.3  96 1280 14319 list at index, double when full, check length inside loop
```