# Dynamic Array-Like Structure In R?

Tags: arrays, performance, r, data-structures, append

In the R programming language, how do I get a dynamic array ([as described on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)) or equivalent data structure?  I want something with the following attributes:

1. O(1) indexing.
2. Amortized O(1) appending.
3. O(N) or less wasted space.
4. Type parametric, i.e. can hold lists, user-defined objects, functions, matrices, etc., not just numbers.
5. Appending without naming should be supported.  Therefore, using an environment won't cut it.

From what I can tell, [using a list doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436688/append-an-object-to-a-list-in-r) because appending to one the following way takes O(N) time, not amortized O(1):

```
foo <- list()
foo[[length(foo) + 1]] <- 1
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's not something like this built into base R.  Is it for a specific use case?  If so, perhaps there's a more R-ish solution that would meet your needs.

Comment: @Aaron:  No specific use case.  I asked because I'm trying to understand R's capabilities as a general-purpose high-level language.  I often do projects that require some statistics/machine learning and some general purpose programming.  I usually do these in a general purpose language with a plain old library for statistics/machine learning instead of R.  Every time I've tried to use it, R has felt too domain specific.  I'm trying to see if I'm missing something and R might work well enough for the general purpose stuff to use in some of my more statistics heavy projects.

Comment: From the perspective of a general programmer, your assessment is probably correct.  R was originally built for statisticians and while it's been getting more like a general-purpose language as it matures, I suspect CS folks will still feel it's missing things. I will be curious to see what happens to it in the next few years; it's already getting a little more like a regular programming language than I'm comfortable with (I'm thinking specifically of S4 methods).

Comment: Also, I see you have some C++ experience; if you haven't already, you should check out [Dirk Eddelbuettel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel)'s [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) package, which makes integrating C++ code in R much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending to the list each time, preallocate it with a fixed length. Then when the list is full, double it, as per the description on the Wikipedia article. This should give you the performance you're after.

```
foo <- vector("list", 1000)

# populate the list, with N >> 1000...
for(i in seq(N))
{
    foo[[i]] <- ...

    # if the list is full, extend it
    if(i == length(foo))
        foo <- c(foo, vector("list", length(foo)))
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.  I thought of doing it manually after I posted, but I'm just surprised there's no obvious, builtin way to do something like this.  Why the heck is the O(N) behavior the default?