# Add named vector to a list

Tags: r

This is horribly basic but I can't seem to figure it out

Suppose I have a list of variable entries:

```
lst <- list(a=1:4, b=rep('k', 5), c=3)
```

If I want to add a vector to this with a specified name I should be able to do so by:

```
c(f=1:5, lst)
```

But instead of creating an entry called 'f' containing 1 2 3 4 5 it creates five entries (f1 - f5) containing one of the numbers each.

How do I supress this behavior?

I know I can use

```
lst$f <- 1:5
```

but I would like to append the list within a function call...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Turn `f` into a list of one, and then concatenate it:

`c(list(f=1:5), lst)`

Answer (score 18):

You can just do:

```
lst[[key]] <- any_object
```

(note the double square brackets `[[]]`)

`any_object` can, of course, be a vector.

This method has the advantage of being usable even if the exact value of `key` is stored in a variable and you don't know it in advance, or if it's the variable being iterated in a `for` loop for example:

```
count <- list()
for (k in c("boys","girls","other")) {
  count[[k]] <- sum(data == k)
}
```

Answer (score 14):

here is a simple function to append one (or more) item to a list:

```
lappend <- function (lst, ...){
lst <- c(lst, list(...))
  return(lst)
}

> a <- list()
> a
list()

> lappend(a,c(1,2,3))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

> lappend(a, c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
[[1]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

Hope that helps!!
Bye.

Answer (score 8):

More versatile solution is with append:

```
append(lst, list(f=1:5), after=0)# after - position to append
```