# fread - skip lines starting with certain character - "#"

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am using the *fread* function in R for reading files to data.tables objects.

However, when reading the file I'd like to skip lines that start with *#*, is that possible?

I could not find any mention to that in the documentation.

Comment: Related [GitHub Issue 856](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/856).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not currently, but it's on the list to do.

Are the # lines at the top forming a header which is more than 30 lines long?

If so, that's come up before and the solution is :

```
fread("filename", autostart=60)
```

where 60 is chosen to be inside the block of data to be read.

From `?fread` :

> Once the separator is found on line autostart, the number of columns
>   is determined. Then the file is searched backwards from autostart
>   until a row is found that doesn't have that number of columns. Thus,
>   the first data row is found and any human readable banners are
>   automatically skipped. This feature can be particularly useful for
>   loading a set of files which may not all have consistently sized
>   banners. Setting skip>0 overrides this feature by setting
>   autostart=skip+1 and turning off the search upwards step.

The default `autostart=30` might just need bumping up a bit in your case.

Or maybe `skip=n` or `skip="string"` helps :

> If -1 (default) use the procedure described below starting on line autostart to find the first data row. skip>=0 means ignore autostart and take line skip+1 as the first data row (or column names according to header="auto"|TRUE|FALSE as usual). skip="string" searches for "string" in the file (e.g. a substring of the column names row) and starts on that line (inspired by read.xls in package gdata).

Comment: thanks a lot, this helps.  They could be anywhere in the file which is kind of odd, but I may just preprocess it and then put it into R...

Comment: @Dnaiel That is indeed odd. Is the file format commonly used in a particular field? If there is an example file on the internet somewhere?

Comment: thanks, seems it won't work for my file since it also have irregular number of columns. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597488/fill-option-for-fread

Comment: @Dnaiel True. I never knew such files existed. What do you think of the `sep2` idea?

Comment: sounds good to me.  What I did now was just to get rid of those extra columns so I am fine with it for now.

Answer (score 22):

fread can read from a piped command that filters out such lines, like this:

```
fread("grep -v '^#' filename")
```