# Force fread to fill appropriate number of columns

Tags: r, data.table

`Fread` from `data.table` package can often handle irregular tables (in my case, a SAM file) with a `fill=TRUE` switch, simply padding the "incomplete" lines with NA's. Sometimes it fails to find the correct maximum number of columns, if they appear late in the table, like in this example:

```
> body = paste0(rep("1 2\n", 1000), collapse="")
> main = paste0(body, "1 2 3\n", body, collapse="")
> fread(main, fill=T)
Warning message:
In fread(main, fill=T) :
  Stopped early on line 1001. Expected 2 fields but found 3.
  Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<1 2 3>>
```

Is there any way to force `fread` to use the correct number of columns with `fill` option, in this case three?

Currently, I just extract the number of columns, pad the first line (with `sed`), `fread` and remove the padding. This removes any benefit from fast loading.

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597488/fill-option-for-fread) old question, pre "fill" option.

Comment: There are a few outstanding bugs like the one you've uncovered... `fread` shouldn't fail in this case. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2727

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/5119

Comment: Came here because I have the same bug, do I understand that fill = integer has never been finished from github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/5119 ? @MichaelChirico ?