# Combine lists without loosing its structure

Tags: r, list

I have a list in a variable named `api_result` which returns the following output in the console when calling it:

```
> api_result
{xml_nodeset (200)}
 [1] <visitor_activity>\n  <id>136212161</id>\n  <prospect_id>2680070</prospect_id>\n  <type>6</type>\n  <type_name>Email</type_name>\n  <det ...
 [2] <visitor_activity>\n  <id>136212163</id>\n  <prospect_id>21304456</prospect_id>\n  <type>6</type>\n  <type_name>Email</type_name>\n  <de ...
etc...
```

I want to append to `api_result` a second list named `api_result2` which has the same length and structure.

When using the `c()` function, the output in the console seems to have changed when calling `api_result`:

```
> api_result <- c(api_result,api_result2)
> api_result
[[1]]
{xml_node}
<visitor_activity>
[1] <id>136212161</id>
[2] <prospect_id>2680070</prospect_id>
[3] <type>6</type>
[4] <type_name>Email</type_name>
```

The problem I'm having with this is that the following code was working fine on the `api_result`:

```
prospect_ids <- xml_text(xml_find_all(api_result, "//prospect_id"))
```

But now it's failing, and returns the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "list"
```

How can I ensure that the structure of the list is maintained, so that my `xml_find_all()` function keeps working?

Comment: `lapply(api_result,function(x){xml_text(xml_find_all(x,"//prospect_id"))}`?

Comment: Thanks, but is there a reason why the original structure is getting lost? Isn't there a way to keep the structure in tact?

Comment: Dunno. Does creating two separate lists then using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848172/appending-a-list-to-a-list-of-lists-in-r) help?