# Here we go again: append an element to a list in R

Tags: r, performance, list, append

I am not happy with the accepted answer to [Append an object to a list in R in amortized constant time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436688/append-an-object-to-a-list-in-r-in-amortized-constant-time)

```
> list1 <- list("foo", pi)
> bar <- list("A", "B")
```

How can I append new element `bar` to `list1`? Clearly, `c()` does not work, it flattens `bar`:

```
> c(list1, bar)
[[1]]
[1] "foo"

[[2]]
[1] 3.141593

[[3]]
[1] "A"

[[4]]
[1] "B"
```

Assignment to index works:

```
> list1[[length(list1)+1]] <- bar
> list1
[[1]]
[1] "foo"

[[2]]
[1] 3.141593

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "A"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "B"
```

What is the efficiency of this method? Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `c(list1,list(bar))`? Please use package microbenchmark to benchmark this yourself.

Comment: Do you prefer performance, elegance or a tradeoff of both? Is all your data known to be string, or could be arbitrary? Please clarify the question title and text accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append an object to a list in R in amortized constant time, O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436688/append-an-object-to-a-list-in-r-in-amortized-constant-time-o1)

Comment: Can someone tell why c() did not work and flattened the values?

Comment: @NaveenGabriel: because semantically `c()` is overloaded. It builds vectors from elements, and also by concatenating vectors.

Comment: Would you be able to explain following behaviour?   While appending the list c() flattens out but not while creating the list.                                  
    a<-list(c("hello, hi"),2)
    > a
    [[1]]
[1] "hello, hi"

[[2]]
[1] 2                                                                                                                                     append(a,c("what","see"))
[[1]]
[1] "hello, hi"

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] "what"

[[4]]
[1] "see"

Comment: @NaveenGabriel It has nothing to do with `c()`, you are observing different behavior between `list()` and `append()`. Can you elaborate why you find it surprising?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Adding elements to a list is very slow when doing it one element at a time. See these two examples:

I'm keeping the `Result` variable in the global environment to avoid copies to evaluation frames and telling R where to look for it with `.GlobalEnv$`, to avoid a blind search with `<<-`:

```
Result <- list()

AddItemNaive <- function(item)
{
    .GlobalEnv$Result[[length(.GlobalEnv$Result)+1]] <- item
}

system.time(for(i in seq_len(2e4)) AddItemNaive(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  15.60    0.00   15.61
```

Slow. Now let's try the second approach:

```
Result <- list()

AddItemNaive2 <- function(item)
{
    .GlobalEnv$Result <- c(.GlobalEnv$Result, item)
}

system.time(for(i in seq_len(2e4)) AddItemNaive2(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  13.85    0.00   13.89
```

Still slow.

Now let's try using an `environment`, and creating new variables within this environment instead of adding elements to a list. The issue here is that variables must be named, so I'll use the counter as a string to name each item "slot":

```
Counter <- 0
Result <- new.env()

AddItemEnvir <- function(item)
{
    .GlobalEnv$Counter <- .GlobalEnv$Counter + 1

    .GlobalEnv$Result[[as.character(.GlobalEnv$Counter)]] <- item
}

system.time(for(i in seq_len(2e4)) AddItemEnvir(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.36    0.00    0.38
```

Whoa much faster. :-) It may be a little awkward to work with, but it works.

A final approach uses a list, but instead of augmenting its size one element at a time, it *doubles* the size each time the list is full. The list size is also kept in a dedicated variable, to avoid any slowdown using `length`:

```
Counter <- 0
Result <- list(NULL)
Size <- 1

AddItemDoubling <- function(item)
{
    if( .GlobalEnv$Counter == .GlobalEnv$Size )
    {
        length(.GlobalEnv$Result) <- .GlobalEnv$Size <- .GlobalEnv$Size * 2
    }

    .GlobalEnv$Counter <- .GlobalEnv$Counter + 1

    .GlobalEnv$Result[[.GlobalEnv$Counter]] <- item
}

system.time(for(i in seq_len(2e4)) AddItemDoubling(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.22    0.00    0.22
```

It's even faster. And as easy to a work as any list.

Let's try these last two solutions with more iterations:

```
Counter <- 0
Result <- new.env()

system.time(for(i in seq_len(1e5)) AddItemEnvir(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  27.72    0.06   27.83 


Counter <- 0
Result <- list(NULL)
Size <- 1

system.time(for(i in seq_len(1e5)) AddItemDoubling(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   9.26    0.00    9.32
```

Well, the last one is definetely the way to go.

Comment: I tried the first approach with `[[]]` with different number of elements: `2e3` runs 100x faster than `2e4`, clearly O(N^2), so the whole list is being copied. On the other hand, assigning to different variable name each time takes about 20x time for `2e5` elements compared to `2e4` elements, which is O(N) -- performance that what I would expect from adding an element to a list.

Comment: Removing `.GlobalEnv$` makes the function faster

Comment: @Megatron, that breaks the code, see my comment to your answer.

Comment: I like the doubling size method, but I always end up with a list longer than what I want. How do i remove the NULL entries at the tail of the list:

Answer (score 23):

It's very easy. You just need to add it in the following way :

```
list1$bar <- bar
```

Comment: This does not address the question of efficiency at all.

Comment: Yeah but it's `very easy...` @Richard

Answer (score 6):

Operations that change the length of a list/vector in R always copy all the elements into a new list, and so will be slow, O(n). Storing in an environment is O(1) but has a higher constant overhead. For an actual O(1) append and benchmark comparison of a number of approaches see my answer to the other question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32870310/264177.

Comment: And by O(1) for storing an item in an environment, I mean amortized O(1) (i.e. on average), but for most cases that is good enough.

Comment: R using a functional programming style will always have problems when adding an element to an existing structure, like in `v <- c(v, newElement)`. Adding or replacing elements via index is not functional programming style, however. I don't know the internal representation of vectors in R, but using a _chunked array_ (individual smaller arrays being linked in a chain to form a larger array basically), parts not affected by the append could be reused unmodified, removing load from the GC.
After all, the base of R is not designed very well, making it quite hard to do simple things, sometimes.

Comment: R vectors are basically plain fixed size C arrays. If something changes the length R just creates a new copy of the entire array. That works great for doing analyses on large data sets but not so well for appending elements one by one.