# R list containing training set and test set objects

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to create 10 folds of my data. What I want to have is a data structure of length 10 (number of folds) and each element of the data structure contains an object/data structure that has two attributes/elements; the training set and the test set at that fold. This is my R code.
I wanted to access for example, the training set at fold 8 by `View(data_pairs[[8]]$training_set)`. But it did not work. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
k <- 10    # number of folds

i <- 1:k  


folds <- sample(i, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)

data_pairs <- list()

for (j in i) {
  
  test_ind <- which(folds==j,arr.ind=TRUE)
  
  test <- data[test_ind,]
  train <- data[-test_ind,]
  
  data_pair <- list(training_set = list(train), test_set = list(test))
  
  data_pairs <- append(x = data_pairs, values = data_pair)
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, you just needed to wrap `values` in a `list` call.

```
k <- 10    # number of folds

i <- 1:k  
folds <- sample(i, nrow(mtcars), replace = TRUE)

data_pairs <- list()

for (j in i) {
  
  test_ind <- which(folds==j,arr.ind=TRUE)
  
  test <- mtcars[test_ind,]
  train <- mtcars[-test_ind,]
  data_pair <- list(training_set = train, test_set = test)
  data_pairs <- append(x = data_pairs, values = list(data_pair))
  #data_pairs <- c(data_pairs, list(data_pair))
}
```

If your data is big I would suggest you read these two posts on more efficient ways to grow a list.

1. [Append an object to a list in R in amortized constant time, O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436688/append-an-object-to-a-list-in-r-in-amortized-constant-time-o1)
2. [Here we go again: append an element to a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046336/here-we-go-again-append-an-element-to-a-list-in-r)

I would also like to point out that you are not creating "folds" of your data. In your case you are attempting a 10-fold cross validation, which means your data should be separated into 10 "equal" sized chunks. Then you create 10 train/test data sets using each fold as the test data and the rest for training.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the package `modelr` could help you here.
In particular I would point you to:

https://modelr.tidyverse.org/reference/resample_partition.html

> ```
> library(modelr)
> ex <- resample_partition(mtcars, c(test = 0.3, train = 0.7))
>
> mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = ex$train)
>
> rmse(mod, ex$test)
> #> [1] 3.229756
> rmse(mod, ex$train)
> #> [1] 2.88216
> ```

Alternatively, producing a dataset of these partitions can be done with:
`crossv_mc(data, n, test = 0.2, id = ".id")`