# Create an ellipsis (...) from list

Tags: r

Is it possible to create a ellipsis (...) from a list? The idea is to be able to do something like:

```
mylist <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
myellipsis <- create_ellipsis(mylist)
print(switch('a', myellipsis)) # output 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `do.call`, which can pass the content of a list to a functions `...` argument:

```
do.call(function(...) print(switch('a', ...)), mylist)
```

Comment: Amazing, know it seems so simple :-). Thanks!

Comment: When your function specified other arguments, join their intended (overriding) values using `c( arg, arg, ..., myList )` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10005644/1418999), for instance: `do.call(function(b=4, ...) print(switch('b', ...)), c(4, myList))
`