# How to append a vector to a list of vectors in R?

Tags: r

This question is related to [an earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436688/append-an-object-to-a-list-in-r-in-amortized-constant-time), except the answer there (use `c()` function) is precisely what was *not* working for me.

First I create a list of vectors and then an additional vector.

```
a_list <- lapply(mtcars, as.integer)
junk <- c(1:length(a_list[[1]]))
```

Now, if use `c(a_list, junk)` (as suggested in the answer to the earlier question), I get a completely different answer from what I get if I say `a_list[["junk"]] <- junk` (the latter yielding the desired result). It seems that what gets added by the former approach is `as.list(junk)`.

How can I add `junk` using `c()` without it being converted to the result of `as.list(junk)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list()` in this way: `c(a_list, junk=list(junk))`.

In trying to work out exactly what was being added in the problematic scenario above (to better formulate my question), I realized that `list` and `as.list` do very different things. By turning junk into a single-element list (using `list()`), it gets added "as is" in the desired fashion.

Actually this was buried in a "show more comments" comment to Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer and (more embarrassingly) in the help for `c()` itself. Quoting the help:

```
## do *not* use
c(ll, d = 1:3) # which is == c(ll, as.list(c(d = 1:3))
## but rather
c(ll, d = list(1:3))  # c() combining two lists
```