# what is time complexity of append (vector / list)?

Tags: r

https://www.programmingr.com/fast-r-append-list/

I don't find the time complexity of the appending operation on  a vector or a list.

Is this documented anywhere?

Suppose that I have n elements, that I have to append one by one. Is there a data structure that has a time complexity of n to append the n elements?

Comment: If you know you *"have n elements,that you  have to append one by one"*, why append one by one? Create a vector of `n` elements of the same type beforehand.

Comment: `append` running time is linear with `n`.

Comment: See context here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669493/read-a-tsv-file-group-by-group-efficiently

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to test the running times of three different ways of assigning a value to a vector.
The first two extend the vector by appending the new element to its end. The last one allocates space by creating a vector with `n` elements and then populates the vector with the new elements.
Times are measured with package `microbenchmark` and medians are plotted with `ggplot2` graphics.

### Atomic vector timings

```
fun <- function(N = 1:10, times = 100){
  if(!require(microbenchmark)){
    stop("Package 'microbenchmark' is not installed")
  }
  out <- lapply(2^N, function(n){
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      c = {
        x <- NULL
        for(i in seq_len(n)) x <- c(x, i)
      },
      append = {
        x <- NULL
        for(i in seq_len(n)) x <- append(x, i)
      },
      allocate = {
        x <- numeric(n)
        for(i in seq_len(n)) x[i] <- i
      },
      times = times
    )
    mb$n <- n
    aggregate(time ~ expr + n, mb, median)
  })
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  row.names(out) <- NULL
  out
}

library(ggplot2)

times <- fun(1:12)

ggplot(times, aes(n, time, color = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

### `list` timings

This function is nearly identical to the function above, but creating and extending objects of class "list".

Surprisingly, now to extend the list by assigning new elements after the current last is faster than `append`.

```
funList <- function(N = 1:10, times = 100){
  if(!require(microbenchmark)){
    stop("Package 'microbenchmark' is not installed")
  }
  out <- lapply(2^N, function(n){
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      List = {
        x <- list()
        for(i in seq_len(n)) x[[i]] <- i
      },
      append = {
        x <- list()
        for(i in seq_len(n)) x <- append(x, i)
      },
      allocate = {
        x <- vector("list", n)
        for(i in seq_len(n)) x[[i]] <- i
      },
      times = times
    )
    mb$n <- n
    aggregate(time ~ expr + n, mb, median)
  })
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  row.names(out) <- NULL
  out
}

library(ggplot2)

times <- funList(1:12)

ggplot(times, aes(n, time, color = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the info for the list as well?

Comment: @user1424739 See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436688/append-an-object-to-a-list-in-r-in-amortized-constant-time-o1?rq=1).

Comment: Do I understand that post correctly? `a <- list(a, list(i))` is the fastest for list? But it does not make sense as it involves rewriting the whole list. Intuitively, assigning by index should be the fastest. Why rewriting the original list could be faster?

Comment: @user1424739 The post is right, that way is the fastest, it's half the time of `append` but the result is not the same, it is a nested lists list, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436688/append-an-object-to-a-list-in-r-in-amortized-constant-time-o1?rq=1#comment57695097_29870770) to Dirk's answer..

Comment: @user1424739 To get an `identical()` result, it would have to be `a <- c(a, list(i))` and performance degrades, as seen in my answer.