# complexity of appending n strings to another string

Tags: r

I want to append a list of strings to another string one by one (not all at once). Based on the description of `paste()`, its complexity should be more similar to `c()` below.

[what is time complexity of append (vector / list)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668604/what-is-time-complexity-of-append-vector-list/68669901)

Is there a way to make repetitive appending strings to another string run in time linear to the total length of the strings appended?

Comment: When you say 'not all at once', when are they arriving that isn't satisfied by [didn't this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668604/what-is-time-complexity-of-append-vector-list/68669901), which is to say, why would `n` be important if the strings aren't at hand?

Comment: See context here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669493/read-a-tsv-file-group-by-group-efficiently

Comment: Would that be similar to [r and awk](https://livefreeordichotomize.com/2019/06/04/using_awk_and_r_to_parse_25tb/), which falls into the 'If you have to ask the price, you can't afford it' category $12 of the TSV? And is this streaming...

Comment: That solution is too complicated. But the idea should be similar. The devil is in the details. It split into files. For my question, I don't want to use files.

Comment: Well, I guess I'd ask, as a client might, how you'd audit your process if these 'items' exist only as (temp) objects without reference to disk?